Error - The positional operator did not find, Mongo db update command not working in Meteor
My stored doc in mongo is :
[{
  _id: 'Bd5r6vmb6bu5R2chQ',
  run_status: true,
  start_time: 2024-06-23T20:19:12.000Z,
  stop_time: 2024-06-23T20:19:12.000Z,
  strategies: [],
  summary: '{"pnl_per":0,"pnl":0,"profit":0,"loss":0,"win":0,"lose":0,"win_per":0,"ppt":0}',
  result: {}
}]

I am using meteor to develop the application with the built in mongo libs.
Now when I am trying to update the existing doc with some new attribute - "flag": true. But ending up getting error :
(node:81184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
Here is my code to update the doc :
        let doc = LiveStrategies.find({}, {sort: {start_time: -1, limit: 1}}).fetch()[0];
        LiveStrategies.update( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { flag: true } },
            (updateErr) => {
               if (updateErr) {
                  console.error('Error updating document:', updateErr);
                  return;
               }
                  console.log('Document updated successfully.');
               }
            }
        );

When i test with find query, its working perfectly fine and getting the doc correctly.
Appreciate your help on resolving this.
Some findings :
My schema is :
StrategySchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Algo Name'
    },
    instrument: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Instrument'
    }
});
LiveStrategySchema = new SimpleSchema({
    start_time: {
        type: Date,
        label: 'Start Time'
    },
    stop_time: {
        type: Date,
        label: 'Stop Time'
    },
    strategies: {
        type: Array,
        label: 'Strategies',
        optional: true
    },
    "strategies.$": StrategySchema
})```
When I am setting the strategies attribute to Object type, not getting any error and update is working fine. But the strategies value is setting to empty.



You didn't use any positional operator ($ sign) in your provided code. Are you sure the exception is caused by the code here?

when i comment out this update query then I am not getting such error.  There is one more warning i am getting as listed here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78666034/meteor-node-error-unable-to-resolve-some-modules-nodestream-web

Fix: The issue is my StrategySchema schema is in diff file and not imported correctly due to which ending up with error while updating/inserting doc in to mongo db. Correctly imported the schema and fixed the issue.
