Meteor node error : Unable to resolve some modules: "node:stream/web"
Meteor version : 2.16
Node version : 18.15.0
When starting my meteor app, I am getting following lines of error but not sure the cause of this :
(node:6749) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'lineno' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6749) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'column' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:6749) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'filename' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:6749) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'lineno' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:6749) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'column' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:6749) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'filename' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:6749) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'lineno' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:6749) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'column' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:6749) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'filename' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:6749) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'lineno' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:6749) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'column' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:6749) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'filename' of module exports inside circular dependency
                                              
Unable to resolve some modules:

  "node:stream/web" in /Users/patel/meteor_workspace/kcon_app_v2/node_modules/node-fetch/node_modules/fetch-blob/streams.cjs (web.browser)
  "worker_threads" in /Users/patel/meteor_workspace/kcon_app_v2/node_modules/node-domexception/index.js (web.browser)
                                              
If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:
                                              
  meteor npm install --save node:stream meteor-node-stubs
                                              
                                              
Unable to resolve some modules:

  "node:stream/web" in /Users/patel/meteor_workspace/kcon_app_v2/node_modules/node-fetch/node_modules/fetch-blob/streams.cjs (web.browser.legacy)
  "worker_threads" in /Users/patel/meteor_workspace/kcon_app_v2/node_modules/node-domexception/index.js (web.browser.legacy)
                                              
If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:
                                              
  meteor npm install --save node:stream meteor-node-stubs


Even I tried running "meteor npm install --save node:stream meteor-node-stubs" but still getting this error. This is not blocking the app execution though. Other part of the app running fine without any issues.

This may be due to an npm package you're using requiring a higher version of Node. Here's a Meteor forum thread where OpenAI is causing this in Meteor 2.16 - https://forums.meteor.com/t/openai-on-meteor2-not-works/61963

Meteor manages its Node and NPM versions internally. Meteor 2.16 is running on Node 14. Meteor 3 is on Node 20.
Make sure that meteor-node-stubs package is installed as instructed. As for stream, try it without the node: prefix when importing.
Ensure that any other packages that you depend on support Node 14, or even better upgrade your app to Meteor 3.0.1 (if possible at this time) so that you can have Node 20, which all packages should support.
